# How to filter by score in Elastic KNN search?

Tags: elasticsearch, knn

I have index with following mapping:

```
{
  "test-2": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "advert_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "fraud": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "photos": {
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "vector": {
              "type": "dense_vector",
              "dims": 3,
              "index": true,
              "similarity": "l2_norm"
            }
          }
        },
        "rating": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how my data is saved in Elastic:

```
 {
    "advert_id": 123,
    "fraud": true,
    "photos": [
      {
        "id": 456,
        "vector": [
          213.32,
          3.23,
          4.21
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want to search data with similar vectors according to KNN algorithm. Here is my query for that:

```
GET /test-2/_knn_search
{
  "knn": {
    "field": "photos.vector",
    "k": 1,
    "num_candidates": 5,
    "query_vector": [213.32, 3.23, 4.22]
  }
}
```

Elastic returns me a score per each hit. Question is how can I get data with score more than `N`? It know about `min_score`, but couldn't apply it in this query.

Comment: As far as i know it is not possible but can you try `post_filter`. I dont have any running instance where knn is available so not able to validate it.

Comment: Thanks! But, what should be inside post_filter? And is it possible to access _score field?

Comment: That i am not sure but you can check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/filter-search-results.html#post-filter) documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that the kNN search API (`/_knn_search`) has been [integrated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-search.html#search-api-knn) into the search API (`/_search`) since Elasticsearch 8.4.0, we can use the `min_score` option as per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/search-search.html#:%7E:text=official%20GA%20features.-,knn,with%20a%20lower%20_score%20are%20not%20included%20in%20the%20search%20results.,-pit) as follows:

```
- GET /test-2/_knn_search
+ GET /test-2/_search
{
  "knn": {
    "field": "photos.vector",
    "k": 1,
    "num_candidates": 5,
    "query_vector": [213.32, 3.23, 4.22]
  },
+ "min_score": N
}
```